# Nuxt.js + vuetify image not loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt.js + Vuetify, but the images are not able to load in my next page files. For example, in my `./pages/browse/index.vue`, I have a vuetify image tag like this:

```
<v-img
  src="~/assets/img/test.png"
  style="width:300px"
  contain
></v-img>
```

The image is located at `assets/img/test.png`, however, whenever I started my Nuxt server, the image won't show up, below is the copied div element from Chrome dev tool:

```
<div class="v-image__image v-image__image--contain" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://localhost:3333/browse/~/assets/img/test.png&quot;); background-position: center center;"></div>
```

The image only works if I do not use Vuetify image component like this:

```
<img
  src="~/assets/img/test.png"
  style="width:300px"
/>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Consider adding images under the `static` folder. `assets` folder is for css/sass/scss files that need to be parsed by webpack. Yes, you can add small images to `assets` which will then be converted to base64 when webpack parses it. But these images can then loaded on the app using only `<img />` tag and not through `<v-img />` component of vuetify.

My understanding is that `<img />` can take a base64 string and then it will load the corresponding image but in `<v-img />` its expecting `src` to be the URL of the image. When you give a base64, boom, it won't load anything!!!

Use `static` folder

```
--static
  --img
```

And then you access image anywhere from the app using

```
<v-img src="img/test.png"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tested it, It's actually <v-img src="/img/test.png"/>

Comment: This works for me without the leading / so YMMV.

Answer (score 6):

Are you using Nuxt 2.0?  If so, note the warning in their webpack section here:

> Warning: Starting from Nuxt 2.0 the ~/ alias won't be resolved
>   correctly in your CSS files. You must use ~assets (without a slash) or
>   the @ alias in url CSS references, i.e. background:
>   url("~assets/banner.svg")

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the `v-img` tag inside the `no-ssr` tag, something like this.

```
<no-ssr>
  <v-img
    src="~/assets/img/test.png"
    style="width:300px"
    contain
  ></v-img>
</no-ssr>
```

If that doesn't work you can try this

```
<v-img
    :src="require('@/assets/img/test.jpg')"
    style="width:300px"
    contain
  ></v-img>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try requiring the image like so: `<v-img :src="require('~/assets/images/background-1.jpg')" />`

That worked for me.

The problem seems to be with v-img rather than nuxt